# Spring Boot Autowired failed - null

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I have 3 classes which are found in different packages in a spring boot application as follows:
Why does `@Autowired` work in certain classes only?Anything I am doing wrong?

```
@Configuration
public class Configurations{
   @Autowired
   Prop prop;  //works fine

   @Bean
   //other bean definitions

}

@Component
public class Prop{
   public void method(){};
}

public class User{
   @Autowired
   Prop prop;  //does not work, null

   public void doWork(){
      prop.method();
   }

}
```

I have also tried the `@PostConstruct`, but same result

```
public class User{
       @Autowired
       Prop prop;  //does not work, null

       @PostConstruct
       public void doWork(){
          prop.method();
       }

    }
```

Comment: change component annotation to bean annotation after that you can use bean annotation and create a method in configuration after that you can use on other methods bean public Prop prop(){...}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Autowired` annotation works only if Spring detects that the class itself should be a Spring bean.

In your first example you annotated `Configurations` with the `@Configuration` annotation. Your `User` class on the other hand does not have an annotation indicating that it should be a Spring bean.

There are various annotations (with different meanings) to make your class being picked up by the Spring container, some examples are `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Configuration`, ... . However, this only works if your class is in a package that is being scanned by the Spring container. With Spring boot, the easiest way to guarantee that is by putting your `User` class in a (sub)package of your main class (the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`).

You can also manually create your bean by writing the following method in your `Configurations`:

```
@Bean
public User user() {
    return new User();
}
```

In this case you don't have to annotate your `User` class, nor do you have to make sure that it is in a package that is being scanned.